# multiple upload image Django 2.0

Tags: django, image, upload

I should upload more images at the same time, but I can not find a solution, you could help me to understand where I'm wrong. Thank you

models:

```
class GalleriaFotografica(models.Model):
  user_galleria = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
  related_name="utente_galleria")
  data_inserimento = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  titolo= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True )
  foto=models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to = 'gallery/')


  class Meta:
        permissions = (
         ("Azienda", "Azienda"),   

         )
        verbose_name="GalleriaFotografica"
        verbose_name_plural="GalleriaFotografica"


  def __str__(self):
    return self.titolo
```

Form:

```
class Form_multimmagine(forms.Form):
 foto = forms.ImageField()
```

Views:

```
 def foto(request):
    userid=request.user.pk

    if request.method=="POST" and 'caricafoto' in request.POST:
     form=Form_multimmagine(request.POST,  request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
        for each in form.cleaned_data['foto']:
            GalleriaFotografica.objects.create(foto=each)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("foto")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one more class to storage your multiples fotos of the same gallery

```
class GalleriaFotografica(models.Model):
  ...
  foto=models.ForeignKey(Foto)

class Foto(models.Model):
  foto=models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to = 'gallery/')
```

Than make 1 Form to get all the images, save all imagens in Foto and link it with the GalleriaFotografica that you want